# What happens after you earn 2015 service medal CSGO

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

So I recently earn the 2015 Service medal by reaching rank 40. Now that I have restarted what happens when I reach rank 40 again. If I do it in 2016 will it give me a 2016 service medal? Will it give me a different 2015 medal? What if I'm rank 39 in 2015 then I turn rank 40 2016? Has valve said anything about this?

Comment: Well no news till know but you can have a look at this https://steamcommunity.com/app/730/discussions/0/541907867782693144/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the update [11/10/2015](https://steamdb.info/forum/657/#reply-2622):

Valve has released a Level 2 for your service badge should you choose to rerank it up to 40 again.  You can see the badge below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Valve never released a statement regarding your questions.

But there are indicators that there will be a different coin next year.

It is not sure, if your rank/level will be reset, beginning next year or if you keep your rank/level, but many say it will be reset.

Also there are no informations what will happen if you reach rank/level 40 twice a year. If you still get XP, weekly drop, or if your will be locked because of MAX level.

Comment: FYI: This answer is out of date. Valve has recently released new information about this.